# Why won't my html render in my header.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a barebone `header.php` file that looks like this so far

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <header class="testB">
        <p>header section</p>
    </header>
```

The header loads into the `index.php` file perfectly fine, however it doesn't render my `<header>` tag with the text.  I just checked out a couple videos and tutorials to see if there's something else I need to do and they all seem to dive right into customizing everything and have it render.  The only thing present is the title of my website which wordpress injects on its own.  Any clue as to why this won't just work like it seems to in the tutorials?

Here's my `index.php` and `footer.php` just so you guys can see the overall setup.

**index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<p class="test">body</p>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**footer.php**

```
<footer>
    <p>footer</p>
    
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Now that I posted this is just hit me that WP strips the `<p>footer</p>` out of the `footer.php` as well while injecting it's "*powered by wordpress*" snippet.  I haven't enabled any WP theme support in the `functions.php` file yet as I haven't seen anyone doing anything like that before diving right into customizing their html.

**UPDATE**

I added the `wp_body_open()` function as suggested below by @amerinediary and my code still isn't rendering in the browser.

Comment: how are you loading it into index.php? show us index.php please

Comment: @Erik I just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `wp_body_open()` function.

> Fire the wp_body_open action.

Which is getting triggered after the opening body tag, via the `do_action( 'wp_body_open' )` hook.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_body_open/

Following are default blank template part boiler plate

```
//header.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' );?>">
<?php wp_header(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php wp_body_open(); ?>
```

```
//index.php
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

```
//footer.php
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` shouldn't be included inside a container as Wordpress is using it to render `<script>`'s tags.

Comment: ok I added that and I don't see any difference.  In fact I wound up deleting the `<p>body</p>` snippet just to see if maybe they were all lining up in the same space for some weird reason and I still see that element even though I removed it from my code.

Comment: I just noticed you don't have the `wp_header()` function in the header file.  Did you remove that on purpose or did you just forget to put it in?

Comment: ok I had the wrong template folder open in VS Code, but the `wp_body_open();` method still isn't making a difference.